# Recursively Scan DOM Elements - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, dom

I have the following html -

```
<a>
  <b>
   ....

    .....
    <input type="button" name="add" onclick="..." value="add another"/>
    </d>
   </b>
....
</a>
```

And I use the following js snippets-

```
/**
 *  Dynamically add a remove button on next to the add button.
 *
 */
addRemoveButton = function(node) {
    if(node.nodeType == 3) {
        if(node.nodeName == "input") {
            if(node.getAttribute("type") == "button") {
                if(node.getAttribute("name") == "add") {
                    var removeButton = node.cloneNode(true);
                    removeButton.removeAttribute("name");
                    removeButton.setAttribute("value", "remove");
                    removeButton.setAttribute("onclick", "");
                    removeButton.setAttribute("id", "");
                    (node.parentNode).appendChild(removeButton);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(node.nodeType == 1) {
        var list = node.childNodes;
        var i = 0;
        while(i<list.length) {
            return addRemoveButton(list[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Now I want to add a input of type button, (remove button), next to the current button shown in the above listing. I tried to do this recursively. But this is not working. Can you find the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code was pretty far off.  You were using the wrong nodeType and had the wrong case on nodeName and there was no reason for the vastly nested if statements.  But, you can make it work recursively like this:

```
addRemoveButton = function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
        if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input" &&
          node.getAttribute("type") == "button" &&
          node.getAttribute("name") == "add") {
            var removeButton = node.cloneNode(true);
            removeButton.removeAttribute("name");
            removeButton.setAttribute("value", "remove");
            removeButton.setAttribute("onclick", "");
            removeButton.setAttribute("id", "");
            (node.parentNode).appendChild(removeButton);
            return;
        } else {
            var list = node.childNodes;
            for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
                // be aware of childNodes changing on us live here
                // when we modify the DOM
                addRemoveButton(list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

addRemoveButton(document.body);
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WCj4b/

Using jQuery (which you also tagged your question with) and continuing to use the clone operation, you can do this:

```
$("input[type='button'][name='add']").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).clone(false)
        .val("remove")
        .removeAttr("name")
        .attr("onclick", "")
        .attr("id", "")
        .insertAfter(this);
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JKsZC/

Or a much, much simpler version that just inserts new HTML rather than clone the existing button:

```
$("input[type='button'][name='add']").after('<input type="button" value="Remove" />');
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vSZwp/

Comment: Showing what the OP did wrong is good, but with libraries like jQuery, there's no need for you write that kind of code

Comment: @JuanMendes - I agree.  That's why I also wrote a jQuery version.

Answer (score 1):

Why recursive? Just to find the existing button? Let jQuery worry about finding it

```
$('input[type=button]').after("<input type='button' value='Remove' />");
```

Tweak this to get your remove button to do what you need.

Comment: The OP's code is trying to create a new button along side the existing one.  Your code is just changing the existing button.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't come close to working properly, but cloneNode is trying to create a duplicate button and then make that duplicate button the "remove" button.  I made a version of the OPs code that does work in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 As far as I can tell, the OP wants to insert a button next to the existing button. My code does exactly that.

Comment: I see now.  Your code does assume there are no other siblings after the button rather than insert it right after the button.